# Codenameone app version issue

Tags: codenameone

I am new with CN1 and I have a simple question.
I created an Android app, and some update versions. The problem is that when I try to change version it doesn't change it on the APK.

I use the field Version at the Properties, but it works only when I use 1, 2 or 3.
But it doesn't work with 1.1 1.2 2.2  etc. When i try to upload the APK to Playstore it says that it has the old version. What am I doing wrong?

I hava also use the android.versionCode=200 or 300 on build hints but it disappears when I close the properties window.

I hope you understand the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the right click preferences or the Codename One -> Codename One Settings app?
There was a bug in the Codename One Settings app which was fixed in the latest update of the plugin

Comment: i used the right click preferences, but i checked now that both have the same version

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/f8f2b9ff8bf97e707ab3f1eb01b72ce0.png this is what play store says

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/bd64a0dfb9458bc0032e1b3cb7a65bc2.png  and https://gyazo.com/aee3b9a44a242d38de2eeffa1b422fb8 are both properties. 2.2 but in google says 210(2.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of `codename1.version` in the `codenameone_settings.properties` make sure it matches the value you set.

Valid values are decimal numbers with up to two digits after the point so:

- 1.11 - Valid
- 1.1 is the same as 1.10 in some platforms...
- 1.111 - the last 1 will be ignored
- 1.1.1 - won't work

Comment: i use the "1.1 is the same as 1.10 in some platforms..." but only takes 1 or 2 or 3. codename1.version matches the version from the properties but playstore says that it has the old version

Comment: Are you using versioned build (targeting an old version of Codename One) or anything specific in the build process?

Comment: Did you define the `android.versionCode` build hint? Notice that it overrides that behavior and hardcodes the version code.

Comment: I am not using versioned build and i checked now that was android.versionCode to build hint. Will try without it now.

Comment: you saved my day, the problem was the build hint (android.versionCode) :| now works good. Thank you very much. Nice support.

Comment: is there an equivalent for iOs (like android.versionCode)?

Comment: All the build hints are here https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html including `ios.bundleVersion`